# How to search for any city starting with either g, b, or a in kibana discover?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I am working with  **kibana discover**  for a while and i want to get all documents which city_names starting with either **g**, **b**, or **a**. 
This is my query with regex: `geoip.city_name: /[gab].*/` but it does not work. 
what is wrong in my query? Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide the version of Kibana? 
Depend on the version of Kibana something like this may work
geoip.city_name:"gab*"
geoip.city_name="gab*"

Comment: Hi. It is the latest version. 7.5.0

Comment: @Gabriel but I don't think this is a right answer because ```gab*```  means all terms start with gab and after this, every word could be

Comment: Sorry I misread : (


You can change in discover to use lucene query language instead of KQL, need to click on KQL and turn it off.
 
I tried your query and it's work as expected, returning city name starting with g b or a

In KQL this query return a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change in discover to use lucene query language instead of KQL, need to click on KQL and turn it off. 
I tried your query and it's work as expected, returning city name starting with g b or a.

In KQL this query return a syntax error.

NB: Changing language work with version 7.5, it may not work with other version as the Kibana interface change often. The query in the question may work with any version that support regex.

(Look like it's the correct answer I moved it from the comment).